# Circular buffer in Simulink implemented as MATLAB function

Tags: matlab, buffer, simulink

I am currently trying to design a very rough but functioning circular buffer for real-time signal processing. For the sake of clarity, I do not have a DSP Toolbox license.

Now, the idea is to buffer a portion of signal within a 1xN window and then further post-process. To achieve this I have been thinking a Simulink block as in the following figure.

[image]

The problem is the following: if the MATLAB function is

```
function y = fcn(Signal,DelayedBuffer,BufferSize)
%#codegen
% y = zeros(1,BufferSize);
persistent Buffer;
Buffer = [Signal DelayedBuffer(1:59-1)];

y = Buffer;
end
```

everything work out just fine.
However, when writing the function as

```
function y = fcn(Signal,DelayedBuffer,BufferSize)
%#codegen
% y = zeros(1,BufferSize);
persistent Buffer;
Buffer = [Signal DelayedBuffer(1:BufferSize-1)];

y = Buffer;
end
```

I receive the following error:

> Data 'y' (#32) is inferred as a variable size matrix, while its
>   specified type is something else.

Do you have any valuable hint on how to suppress this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB Function block works by generating compiled code for the MATLAB code you enter. In order to generate code the block needs to know the size, type and complexity of all the inputs and variables you use. It infers the size of the variables and outputs based on the size of the inputs. When you create Buffer using

```
Buffer = [Signal DelayedBuffer(1:59-1)];
```

it is easy to see that the size of the Buffer is 59 elements (assuming Signal is scalar). MATLAB Function block can infer this size and also identify that y which is assigned Buffer also is of the same size. In the second case,

Buffer = [Signal DelayedBuffer(1:BufferSize-1)];

BufferSize is coming from input and MATLAB Function block does not know this value when compiling. So it has to assume that this value can change which leads to a variable-sized data. i.e It cannot determine the size of Buffer while compiling. 'y' which is assigned Buffer is also inferred as a variable-sized data. The error message indicates that you may have specified output size in the block's parameters as a fixed size. There is a check-box in the blog's "Ports and Data Manager" dialog that indicates the output port is variable size. You can check that box to see that works. But in your case, for a circular buffer, it is better to use persistent variable which gives you fixed-size data.

It your BufferSize does not need to change within one simulation try using it as a parameter to the MATLAB Function block instead of an input. You can do this also through the "Ports and Data Manager" dialog.

Comment: Well, the size of the buffer stays constant over the simulation length, but I would like allowing the user to tune the size of the buffer, so as to find out which sizes retrieves the best results. I tried assigning the 'BufferSize' as parameter, but I do not clearly understand how to pass it on to the function, since the port is not connected anymore with the function.

Comment: Once you make some input as parameter you can define it using the same  name in a model workspace or MATLAB base workspace. You can just do BufferSize = 59; at the command line. You should not make this Tunable since you do not need to change it within one simulation. You can change it between simulations.